# Fibonacci is giving me problems, what’s wrong with this code?

Tags: javascript

```
function isFibo(currentValue, previousValue, valueToCheck) {
    return currentValue > valueToCheck ? false : valueToCheck == currentValue ? true : isFibo(previousValue + currentValue, valueToCheck);
}
```

It’s a hacker rank test with bad syntax. I’m supposed to correct the syntax errors of `isFibo`. When adding current val + previous val, they should give me the next value.

Comment: What problems, please? I don’t think we can work with what you’ve given us so far. Please give a full working example including a call to your method, expected result and observed result. Then I am sure we can help. PS Your code doesn’t look like Java syntax? `function`? Could it be JavaScript instead?

Comment: your function expects 3 arguments `isFibo(currentValue, previousValue, valueToCheck)` but you are giving it 2 `isFibo(previousValue + currentValue, valueToCheck)`

Comment: What language is this? Java methods do not start with 'function'. There is no return type. There is no (public, protected, private) modifiers. Also, the isFibo arguments have no type.

Comment: its a hacker rank test with bad syntax.

Comment: im suppose to correct the bug syntax of fibo when adding current val + previous val , they should give me the next val

Comment: [Link to original problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/codesprint5/challenges/is-fibo)

Answer (score 1):

```
public static boolean isFibo(int valueToCheck, int previousValue, int currentValue) {
        return previousValue > valueToCheck ? false : valueToCheck == previousValue ? true : isFibo(valueToCheck, previousValue + currentValue, previousValue);
    }
```

This is a working solution in java..

HOLA!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Trusting that this had been supposed to be Java (as your tag said and as you have not denied in the comments):

1. Instead of `function` before the method name, `isFibo`, you should probably give one or more modifiers and under all circumstances the return type.
2. You need to declare the type of each parameter (inside the round brackets in the header).
3. In the recursive call to `isFibo` you need to pass the correct number of arguments — as many as the number of parameters.

I am on purpose limiting myself to answering your question — *what’s wrong* — and not showing you any corrections. You will learn more from writing those yourself (and if I had wanted to solve the HackerRank challenge, I would do so on HackerRank. not here). If there’s something I have written that you do not understand, in the first round use your search engine or your text book for any words and expression that you may be in doubt about. Your follow-up questions are welcome in the comments under this answer, though.